# Create multiple classes from continuous variables Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

I would like to convert my continuous predictor variable (stock returns) into a categorical variable (5 bins, either 5 bins with equal number of stocks OR absolute thresholds, say -30% to -20%, then -19% to -10% etc.)

Is there some Python package that does this? scikit learn etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is either [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for absolute thresholds or [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) for equal sized bins.

Comment: Ahh, very nice. Thank you Ingo!!

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) is also a useful option for discretizing stuff