# Categorization with scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I have asked in a previous post how to categorize a continuous predictor variable. It was suggest to use pd.cut or pd.qcut:

[Create multiple classes from continuous variables Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433738/create-multiple-classes-from-continuous-variables-python)

I am wondering what these functions do:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format

Would it maybe make sense to let that package take care of the classification rather than doing it myself?

Comment: `MultiLabelBinarizer` does not make bins, it will assign each float a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiLabelBinarizer` does not make bins, it will assign each one a different category.

For example, if we have a `y` as in the example, we have 4 unique values, `MultiLabelBinarizer` will return an array of shape (4, 2). But if we have float we will return a different category for each number.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
y = [[1.1, 2.2], [1.3, 1.4, 1.1]]
print(MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y))
# [[1 0 0 1]
#  [1 1 1 0]]
```

So first you need to make the bins (in this case round):

```
# round the y
round_y = []
for arr in y:
    round_y.append([round(i) for i in arr])
print(round_y)
# [[1, 2], [1, 1, 1]]

print(MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(round_y))
# [[1 1]
#  [1 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation Lucas!!